# AttributeError: 'Program' object has no attribute 'frame'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I'm new to python and cant figure out why the error 'AttributeError: 'Program' object has no attribute 'frame' is happening.
Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *


class Program():

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master, bg='ghostwhite')
        frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        #menu
        self.menu = Menu(frame)
        self.frame.config(menu = self.menu)
        self.select = Menu(self.menu)
        self.menu.add_cascade(label = 'Select', menu = self.new)
        self.select.add_command(label = 'Select all', command = self.new)

     def new():
        print ('newfile')

root = Tk()
program = Program(root)
w = 800
h = 500
ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
root.title('Cafe Au Lait')

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Use `self.frame = Frame(master, bg='ghostwhite')` and `self.frame = ...` in the line below as well, as well as `self.menu = Menu(frame)`.

Comment: Or replace `self.frame` with `frame` instead, if you don't need it elsewhere in the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
    self.frame.config(menu = self.menu)
```

you are trying to access the `self.frame` attribute which does not exist - all you have at this point is the `frame` local variable.

If you need to keep a reference to `frame` for other needs, first make it an attribute:

```
def __init__(self, master):
    self.frame = Frame(master, bg='ghostwhite')
    self.frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    self.menu = Menu(self.frame)
    # etc
```

Else just replace `self.frame.config(menu=self.menu)` by `frame.config(menu=self.menu)`

Comment: Hey thanks that seemed to fix that problem but now I am receiving the error: _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-menu". Any ideas as to why this is?.